# Addressing an array of pointers in asm

Tags: nasm, x86-64

I have a routine which I can call like this:

```
mov rdi, struc_point
mov rsi, struc_color
call put_pixel
```

Now, I would like to create something like an array of pointers to have a color table. What I have now is this, and it's not working:

```
color_table:
dq 0 ; null color
dq struc_color1
dq struc_color2
dq struc_color3
; etc..., the colors are defined somewhere else
```

Now, I would like to do something like that with it in the end:

```
mov rbx, 2 ; index into color table
mov rdi, struc_point
mov rsi, qword [color_table+8*rbx]
call put_pixel
```

What is going wrong? There are no compiler errors, but when I run this, all animations stop. `rsi` should contain the address of `struc_color`, see first snippet. The program works if I hardcode this color (`mov rsi, struc_color`).

This is in x86_64 asm, booted directly without any OS.

Comment: When I run this, all animations stop. There are no compiler errors. `rsi` should contain base address of struc color, see first snippet. The program works if I hardcode the color, thus omitting the color table (`mov rsi, sky_color`) - every pixel is displayed correctly in this one color. So the problem seems to be with the "color table" thing.

Comment: Instead of 64bit pointers, why not just store colors directly in the color table?  Or if the definitions you're pointing to are stored contiguously, you could store an 8 or 16bit index.    BTW, `mov ebx, 2` would save an instruction byte (the REX prefix), unless your assembler already leaves it off when possible.

Comment: The snippet that uses the table is different from the snippet that doesn't.  One: it clobbers `rbx`.  Do you save/restore `rbx` in this function?  (Assuming you're using a calling convention where `rbx` is a callee-saved register.)  Is `struc_color2` the same as `struc_color`?  Have you tried running your homebrew OS in bochs or another x86 simulator / emulator, so you can debug it from the outside?  e.g. see where it's stuck?

Comment: @PeterCordes it was actually `rax` being destroyed by `put_pixel`. Thanks for all the other ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. The code I wrote above was in fact correct and worked well.

The problem was located inside of `put_pixel` which did not save `rax`. And I was actually using `rax` just a couple of lines earlier and storing the data to be displayed in it. This lead to `put_pixel` throwing the program off course on first run.

Comment: You'll probably find your code becomes more efficient if you designate a few registers as call-clobbered, so functions can use them without saving/restoring them.  I'd suggest using one of the standard ABIs, like the SysV ABI (see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).  The Windows 64bit calling convention is generally worse IMO, but having some vector registers call-preserved is interesting (the Windows ABI designates too many vector regs as call-preserved, though.  Having most of them available as scratch regs is probably better).